# What type of date format is this?

Tags: vba, date, format, date-formatting

I have a value like this`2015-12-18 11:14:20.72+05:30` and i would like to convert it to `yyyy/dd/mm` format. I would like to know what format is the date I mentioned above.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: I could not format it using Format(value,"mm/dd/yyyy"). Do you have any idea on how to format this?

Comment: Not without knowing which language/library you're using. Java?

Comment: Then no, I have no idea. Did you google "vba iso 8601"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an ISO date with more information than VBA is designed to handle. For example, at the end it appears to have the difference to GMT for the configuration on which it was generated. VBA wasn't designed to work with milliseconds or GMT information - the programming language hasn't been updated for over a decade, except for new objects in the Office applications.

If you cut off the .72+05:30 VBA can work with the rest of the information. For example:

```
year = DatePart("yyyy", "2015-12-18 11:14:20") 'returns 2015
hour = DatePart("h",  "2015-12-18 11:14:20") 'returns 11
```

You can trim off the end using string manipulation, for example:

```
sDateInfo = "2015-12-18 11:14:20.72+05:30"
sDateTrimmed = Left(sDateInfo, Instr(sDateInfo, ".")-1)
sDateFormatted = Format(sDateTrimmed, "yyyy/dd/mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that VBA could not directly convert this timestamp. What I did is just to get the first 10 characters and then convert it to Date.